# How do I print the Processes data from gnome-system-monitor?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, printing, system-monitor

I would like to print a list of active processes. I have no idea how to do so. Can you offer suggestions? An alternative could be a routine that logs processes so I can print from the log file. I believe that something may be available of which I am unaware.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux > ~/Desktop/process.txt
```

The above command will saves the information about active processes in a file `process.txt` under `~/Desktop` folder.

Comment: ps aux does not show the process name which is about the only way I can identify what process is running. Is there a way to include other data that is available under the Processes tab of the gnome-system-monitor?

Comment: command field shows you the command which initiates the process.